# Broadcast Receiver Long Binary SMS

Tags: android

I have a problem when receiving a long **binary** SMS. The client is supposed to receive multipart binary SMS. Upon searching stackoverflow, people have mentioned that onReceive() shall be fired only once. From there you can concatenate the multiple SMS.

I am not sure if that's the same when sending binary SMS. I receive 2 SMS, and onReceive is fired twice. The SMS are separate from each other making it impossible to concatenate.

AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <receiver
        android:name="com.myapp.smsnotification.SMSReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data
                android:host="localhost"
                android:port="9515"
                android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

SMSReceiver.java

in my onReceive()

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
    }
    try {
        if (messages.length > -1) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage message = messages[i];
                os.write(message.getUserData());
            }
            byte[] stream = os.toByteArray();
            // do something with stream
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it was not an issue with the client side but in the server side. They didn't include in the User Data Header the part to indicate that the message is a concatenated SMS.

If the protocol is followed, Android will be able to detect it and handle them accordingly, waiting for all SMS to arrive and fire the SMS broadcast receiver once containing all received SMS.

Comment: Hi @mussharapp, how do you verify your conclusion?